# How to extract lossless image from video with FFmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, images, jpeg, extract

I have a 5s fps25 mp4 video and I use the following command to extract jpg images from the video

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -r 1 -q:v 1 output_%01d.jpg
```

The images are extracted successfully, but jpg files quality isn't good enough.

How can I extract better quality images?

Comment: try using value 2 instead of 1 in -qscale:v

Answer (score 12):

Try

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -r 1 -q:v 1 -qmin 1 -qmax 1 output_%01d.jpg
```

If not good enough, use

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -r 1 output_%01d.bmp
```

and use another JPEG encoder.

Comment: i get error-`"qmin and or qmax are invalid, they must be 0 < min <= max"` using first command..i tried setting-`"-qmin","0", "-qmax","1"` but still same error..

Comment: See updated cmd.

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg option `-qscale` is the image quality factor, for series images extraction from H264 input videos,I'm not sure if it works the same for mp4 video, but you can try it with the following command

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -qscale:v 2 output_%03d.jpg
```

more information please see source reference [here](https://qastack.cn/programming/10225403/how-can-i-extract-a-good-quality-jpeg-image-from-an-h264-video-file-with-ffmpeg).

ffmpeg official document [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html).